# How to expand variable in aws-cli --query parameter

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-security-group

I am trying to write a very simple script and am fairly new to aws cli. With my script, I am outputting all the security group ids that are allowing all open IPs (0.0.0.0/0), and I am using

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=ip-permission.cidr,Values='0.0.0.0/0' --region "$region" --query 'SecurityGroups[*].{Name:GroupName,vpc:VpcId,sg:GroupId,Region:"$region"}' --output table.
```

The `region` is defined in the earlier part of the script since I am going through all the regions.

However, when the table is presented, The column for region says `None`. How can I include the region with only `aws ec2 describe-security-groups` filter so it doesn't output None?

Comment: region is not part of the object key in the result. Why do you want to add that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `region` does not exist in the output of the command, so you can not look for value `region`.

[describe-security-groups-output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html)

So the other option is to expand the value of `$region variable` and then use escape sequence to print the value as a static value.

```
Region:\``echo $region`\`
```

you can use

```
export region=us-east-1 && aws ec2 describe-security-groups --region=$region --filters Name=ip-permission.cidr,Values='0.0.0.0/0' --query "SecurityGroups[*].{Name:GroupName,vpc:VpcId,sg:GroupId,Region:\``echo $region`\` }" --output table
```

Sample output

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                               DescribeSecurityGroups                                |
+-------------------------------+------------+------------------------+---------------+
|             Name              |  Region    |          sg            |      vpc      |
+-------------------------------+------------+------------------------+---------------+
|  launch-wizard-17             |  us-west-2 |  sg-12345  |  vpc-12345 |
```

`AWS-cli` look against region, so you can get all-region at once, to get `security group` from all region use below script.

```
#!/bin/bash

for region in $(aws ec2 describe-regions --query "Regions[].RegionName" --output text); do 
    echo "SG for region ${region}"
    aws ec2 describe-security-groups --region=$  --filters Name=ip-permission.cidr,Values='0.0.0.0/0' --query "SecurityGroups[*].{Name:GroupName,vpc:VpcId,sg:GroupId,Region:\``echo $region`\` }" --output table
done
```

[aws-cli-cheatsheet](https://github.com/Adiii717/aws-cli-cheatsheet)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much!!!!!