# Retrieving files from s3 with content-type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Is there any proper way to retrieve files from s3 with the Content-type using python or AWS CLI?

I've searched and made some queries as below but the first one seems not as intended.

```
aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive s3://<Bucket Name> | egrep '*.jpg*'
```

And the following query seems working but it also returns 404 errors.

```
for KEY in $(aws s3api list-objects --bucket <Bucket Name> --query "Contents[].[Key]" --output text) do aws s3api head-object --bucket <Bucket Name> --key $KEY --query "[\`$KEY\`,ContentType]" --output text | awk '$2 == "image/jpeg" { print $1 }'done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reason is, the variable is not expending in the query parameters

```
--query "[\`$KEY\`,ContentType]"
```

Here you can look for more details.

[How to expand variable in aws-cli --query parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62805414/how-to-expand-variable-in-aws-cli-query-parameter)

so you can try this as just test it out and seems like working.

```
#!/bin/bash
ContentType="application/octet-stream"
BUCKET=mybucket
MAX_ITME=100 
OBJECT_LIST="$(aws s3api list-objects --bucket $BUCKET --query 'Contents[].[Key]' --max-items=$MAX_ITME --output text | tr '\n' ' ' )"; 
for KEY in ${OBJECT_LIST}
do  
aws s3api head-object --bucket $BUCKET --key $KEY --query "[\``echo $KEY`\`,ContentType]"  --output text | grep "$ContentType"
done
```

[image]